# Android Map NOT showing. Only Grids

Tags: android, google-maps

**PROBLEM IS  SOLVED**
*Short Summary of solution: Make sure you are not classes of api v1. Right now when I was working, the emulator was useless to test the application. So test it on actual device.
Finally if application run correctly but don't show the map then you have problem with key.
What I noticed here is the catlog don't say that key is wrong, application run, but map is not shown.*

I'm trying for 2 days to make a single simple Google map android application that just show map on Activity but failed. Tried every tutorial upto google's second page. Nothing works. What works a bit is only the application that I'm following in book But it shows grid and no MAP. Usually people gives answer of that the key is wrong but it is not. My key is right I worked accurately in generating key.
I'm using Google Maps Android API v2 key.

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="0AeGR0UwGH4pYmhcwaA9JF5mMEtrmwFe8RobTHA"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.lbs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lbs"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.lbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.lbs.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.lbs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyB1RpoULFVTRkXREZX0ZAwxcz4_75Y0HYc" />

</manifest>
```

[image]

On catlog, when application is running I'm getting this

```
IOException processing: 26
java.io.IOException: Server returned: 3
    at android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.map.BaseTileRequest.readResponseData(BaseTileRequest.java:115)
```

**Update 1:**
**After all above, As i read at some places the code may only be for API key v1. So I followed a tutorial completely from start at https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435
and I ended up with this**

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**
Now I tried to make it work on actual Android device. It's android 2.3.
So doing a bit more work. I end up with in my activity

[image]

and what I can see at my CatLog is

[image]

So the map is not still showing... Please help...

**Update 3:**
The problem was in API key. I could not see anything in logcat about the wrong key. application  runs but don't show the map. So I regenerated the key.
AND HERE WE GO 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you produce the key for Google Maps API V2 but you are trying to use Google Maps API V1 object `MapView`:

```
  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="0AeGR0UwGH4pYmhcwaA9JF5mMEtrmwFe8RobTHA"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
```

Instead you should use `MapFramgent` or `SupportMapFragment`, depending on what API level you are targeting, you can get a full explanation on how to integrate Google Maps API V2 in your application in this guide I wrote on this matter:

[Google Maps API V2](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

**UPDATE:**

The second screen shot is what you suppose to get on the emulator. `Google Play Services` are not installed on the emulator and that the reason you see what you see. try to test this app on a device with `Google Play Services` installed and it should work.

Comment: Meanwhile you were answering, I have followed the tutorial already and what result I got there, you can in the last part of my question. I edited question. Kindly have a look at last part of my question.

Comment: Don't you think following this tutorial https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527 and installing those apk files that are mentioned in tutorial will make it work on this emulator?

Comment: It should but not with the current Google Play Serivices library you are downloading using the Android SDK Manager. if you follow the comments in this post you will find this link: http://venomvendor.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html if you download revision 4 from there and use it for your project as well as installing those file on the emulator, then it should work.

Comment: Now I've tried on actual android device and application is running. But not showing map. Kindly have a look at the last 2 pictures of my question edit (Update-2 in my question).

Comment: Now the problem was in API key. I regenerated it and it worked. Thank you

Comment: You welocme, @ArslanAfzal. Glad you could get it running.

Answer (score 1):

Check for this!
I also had the similar problem.This worked for me!.
1)Go to Google API Console,were the API key was generated.
2)Click on sevices(appears on options in left).
3)Hover and search for Google Maps Android API v2.
4)Enable it(initially it was off hence only grey tiles appeared).

Answer (score 0):

In the Google APIs Console, under your key for Android apps, make sure you added both fingerprints — the debug and the release one.

Comment: It asked for sha1 code and package name. I inserted that and console gave me key. Am I still missing something?

Comment: There's two different sha1, one for the release version of the app (which is in your keystore) and another one for the debug version (at ~/.android/debug.keystore). Add the debug one too after the release key. I had a similar problem when I was doing my first map application time ago and that was the reason.

Comment: After now I got the key, I can't see any button or textbox in console to add another key. Between right now I just want it to run on emulator. That's it. So if you think it is necessary, then how should I add other key?

Comment: Use the "Edit allowed Android apps" link.