# Android: Display Google Map in grids of specific area

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I have requirement of displaying google map as grids of X km<sup>2</sup> in Android. Also while zoom in/out the grid size will be updated to enclose the particular area. I am not sure whether it is possible or not? If possible , please help how can we implement this. thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried reading this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738438/android-api-with-google-map-displays-grid / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168216/android-map-not-showing-only-grids / https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay

Comment: Is it possible to split entire map with 1km area square using polygon ?